# "Invalid Equation" on codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php but It's ok on stackedit.io

Tags: equations

I have this equation in latex:

```
\{\Theta, \{\phi, \psi \}\} + \{\phi, \{\psi,\Theta \}\} + \{\psi, \{\Theta, \phi\}\} = 0
```

and codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php show me "Invalid Equation":

[image]

but stackedit.io/ is ok:

[image]

Because codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php doesn't work?

Comment: While MathJax uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to write with codecogs.com. I think the problem is that codecogs.com doesn't work very well.
If you try with other equation you can obtain:

```
\left \{  \alpha  \right \}
```

[image]

```
\left \{  \beta   \right \}
```

**ERROR**

I think if you use braces site works only with a small number of latex commands.